# Cannot create swap space in Ubuntu 20 installation

Tags: partitioning, uefi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20 into a toshiba laptop with 8 GB of RAM.

I'm following all the steps as usual, and for some reason I cannot successfully go foward the partition table part of the process.

I created the partitions according to the [Ubuntu docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace).

### This are my BIOS settings (UEFI boot)

[image]

### And here's how I've set the partitions:

[image]

**In short:**

> a swap partition of 11GB

> an efi partition of 250 MB a root partition

> at / with the rest of the disc.

I´m not sharing this disc with windows, I've erased everything but the "erase everything" option kept throwing an error. So, **this is NOT a double boot**.

I know that I should give the swap space at least the same amount of your RAM, so I've given it 11 GB according to [this suggestion](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq) at the docs.

### Now, after clicking on "Install now" I get this error:

[image]

**What can I do?**

Comment: Ubuntu uses swap file now, does not need swap partition.  Are you planning to use hibernation?  If not can do away with swap partition.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried just forgetting about the swap partition, and it shows an error "The EFI file system creation ... failed"...

Comment: Your EFI is showing as formatted to ext4, try fat32 format.

Comment: I've tried it and it says that there's no EFI partition. The partition that you see in the image is the one created as an "efi partition" type.

Comment: This link might help more than I, might need to use boot as mount point for EFI.  Would start over after reading.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: If you just let the Ubuntu Installer create partitions on its own, it'll work fine. No manual partitioning required.